# Adding event handlers to object

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling, userform

Is there a way to add keydown and keyleft event handler to image object in a user form? I can only see mouseup/down/move,error,dragover,dropandpaste.

I notice with an option button, the event keydown/keyleft is available but not for image.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Given that you can't type in an image control, no. What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: What is this `KeyLeft` event of which you speak?

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks @Rory is there anyway to code them in do you know?

Comment: You can't add events that don't exist without subclassing, but the image control can't receive focus. See my answer for a proxy approach.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I’m pretty sure it was in the drop down when selecting which event you want. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add event handlers that don't exist for that control type (other than by subclassing, but the image control doesn't receive focus anyway), but an image control can't receive the focus, and therefore can't receive keystrokes anyway.

You talk about `KeyDown` and `KeyLeft` events. While some controls have `KeyDown`, `KeyPress` and `KeyUp` events, there aren't any controls that have a `KeyLeft` event. Do you perhaps mean to capture the `KeyDown` event, and then detect whether the `Down` arrow or `Left` arrow was the key that pressed down?

However, there are a few options:

1. Wire up the `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` event (depending upon which type of key information you require) for the UserForm, and then act upon the image control. This is probably only of use if you're happy for keypresses to be handled by the form, regardless of which other control might be selected.
2. Add a proxy control, say a `TextBox` that does receive `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events, and place it **behind** the image control. That way, when the user tabs to the textbox, you can add a border to the image to make it *look* like it is selected, and then have the textbox key events act upon the image. If a user clicks on the image, instead of tabbing between controls, you can set the image's click event to give the textbox the focus, and again, handle the key events for the textbox as a proxy for the image control.

Comment: this seems to be a great workaround. I will try it later and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: I used the frame and inserted a picture to the frame. Now when the frame moves, so does the picture. I wasn't able to use the arrow keys so I used WSAD instead and works a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on *what are you trying to achieve* which you didn't specify.

`Image` obviously doesn't have `Key-events` so it can't be used directly.
One possible solution could be to use `Frame` control which has a `Picture` property and has `KeyDown` event, so you can catch key-downs when the frame has focus. Example:

```
Private Sub FrameWithPicture_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    ' Compare KeyCode with predefined vbKey-Constansts, e.g. for key-left:
    If KeyCode = vbKeyLeft Then
        ' left arrow key was pressed, do somthing
    Else
        ' all other keys were pressed, do something else 
    End If
End Sub
```

Or you could add `Image` control to this frame and when key-down event occurs on the frame, then perform some action on this image like this: `FrameWithImage.Controls.Item(0).BackColor = vbRed` etc. HTH

Comment: How does the frame receive focus, if there aren't any selectable controls within it?

Comment: @ThunderFrame frame can receive focus even without controls. Tabstop must be set to true.

Comment: @ThunderFrame or maybe not :). If you are right, then it is necessary to add image control into the frame.

Comment: image control won't receive focus either?

Comment: @ThunderFrame OK, I have checked that when an image is inside of frame then the frame gets focus on tab and it receives the key-down events.

Comment: Good to know. Nice solution. I guess you can remove the frame border too?

Comment: @ThunderFrame yes, border style and special effect can be used on frame.